# How to use certificate authentication for custom sockets TCP protocol?

Tags: c#, authentication, networking, certificate

I know that WCF has certificate authentication. How can I do the same thing for my custom sockets protocol? What classes should I use to verify certificates? What data should I transfer between parties? What are the required steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to use SSL:

On the server side, you can wrap a `NetworkStream` in an `SslStream` and authenticate using a `X509Certificate`:

```
SslStream stream = new SslStream(networkStream, false);
stream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate, false, SslProtocols.Default, false);
```

The `false` in that second call controls whether the server requires the client to have a certificate as well.

[This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dcook/archive/2008/11/25/creating-a-self-signed-certificate-in-c.aspx) contains code to generate a self-signed certificate, handy during development.

On the client side, you have to provide a validation callback:

```
SslStream stream = new SslStream(networkStream, false, ValidateRemoteCertificate);
stream.AuthenticateAsClient(RemoteHost);
```

You can supply client certificates in the AuthenticateAsClient overloads, if desired.

```
private bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Here you decide whether self-signed certificates are OK
    if (allowAnyCertificateAnyway)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I hope this helps, it uses `NetworkStream` which in the end is simply a wrapper around `Socket`. This is all built in in the framework, and you can read/write from/to the `SslStream` as if it was a regular `NetworkStream`.

Comment: What if I want to use certificates only for authentication but not for encryption? Is there an easier way for that?

Comment: If you set the `leaveInnerStreamOpen` parameter of `SslStream` to `true`, you can close the `SslStream` after both sides have successfully executed their `AuthenticateAsXxxxx()` method. Then you can continue sending unencrypted data over the `NetworkStream` or socket. I don't know if this is "the way to go" or considered "the worst hack ever", but it does work.